# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower' Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to make category prediction which basically I have this 3 columns 'First Name','Last Name','Gender' and my goal  is that to predict the category of input variable 'test_x' so in below code I inserted 'Male' as my input and I was expecting for 'Gender' as my output but I got this error instead: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'`.

```
import pandas as pd 
import nltk

class Employee_Category:
    FIRST_NAME = "FIRST_NAME"
    LAST_NAME = "LAST_NAME"
    GENDER = "GENDER"

data = pd.read_excel("C:\\users\\HP\\Documents\\Datascience task\\Employee.xlsx")
data = data.drop(['Age','Experience (Years)','Salary'],axis='columns')

train_x = [data['First Name'],data['Last Name'],data['Gender']]
train_y = [Employee_Category.FIRST_NAME,Employee_Category.LAST_NAME,Employee_Category.GENDER]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=True)
vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_x)

# Train the model
clf_svm = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf_svm.fit(vector,train_y)

# Predict
test_x = vectorizer.transform(['Male']) # Expected output: "GENDER"
clf_svm.predict(test_x)
```

This is the head of dataset:

[image]

I have done several googling but I couldn't solve the error nor do I even understand the error in the first place so please help and give explanation for why this occurred!.

Comment: What is the full traceback? There is no `lower` in your code

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-93-b084289d383c> in <module>
     
      vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=True)
---> vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_x)
     
      # Train the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have to flatten your input matrix, so that every word is assigned to a label. The code below works for me:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

class Employee_Category:
    FIRST_NAME = "FIRST_NAME"
    LAST_NAME = "LAST_NAME"
    GENDER = "GENDER"

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['First Name','Last Name','Gender'])
data.loc[0,:] = ['Arnold','Carter','Male']
data.loc[1,:] = ['Arthur','Farrell','Male']
data.loc[2,:] = ['Richard','Perry','Male']
data.loc[3,:] = ['Ellia','Thomas','Female']

train_x = data.to_numpy().flatten()
train_y = len(data)*[Employee_Category.FIRST_NAME,Employee_Category.LAST_NAME,Employee_Category.GENDER]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=True)
vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_x)

# Train the model
clf_svm = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf_svm.fit(vector,train_y)

# Predict
test_x = vectorizer.transform(['Male']) # Expected output: "GENDER"
print(clf_svm.predict(test_x))
```

returns: `['GENDER']`